# Need assistance with collision script

Tags: javascript, collision

So I am currently working on a game as my schoolproject for a programing course, and I have stod upon a problem where it seems like the player cant die by "touching" the walls that are located on the top and the bottom, The left and Right walls works though. 
Here is the code for the walls:

```
    class Wall{
        constructor(x, y, w, h, c){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = w;
            this.height = h;
            this.color = c;
        }

        draw(ctx){
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    var Wall1 = new Wall(0,0, 3, 850, "cyan"); 
    var Wall2 = new Wall(600, 0, 3, 850, "cyan");
    var Wall3 = new Wall(0, 425, 600, 3, "cyan");

function collision(ctx){
    //Spelare 1
    if(NotP1.x < Wall1.x + Wall1.width && NotP1.x > Wall1.x){
        NotP1.x = NotP2.x;
        return alert("Player 1 died, Player 2 Wins");
    }
    else if(NotP1.x > Wall2.x + Wall2.width && NotP1.x > Wall2.x){
        NotP1.x = NotP2.x;
        return alert("Player 1 died, Player 2 Wins");
    }
    else if(NotP1.x > Wall3.y + Wall3.height && NotP1.x > Wall3.y){
        NotP1.x = NotP2.x;
        return alert("Player 299 died, Player 2 Wins");
    }

    //Spelare 2
    if(NotP2.x < Wall1.x + Wall1.width && NotP2.x > Wall1.x){
        NotP2.x = NotP1.x;
        return alert("Player 2 died, Player 1 Wins");
    }
    else if(NotP2.x > Wall2.x + Wall2.width && NotP2.x > Wall2.x){
        NotP2.x = NotP1.x;
        return alert("Player 2 died, Player 1 Wins");
    }
    Wall3.draw(ctx);    
}
```

Comment: You have hardcoded your game, it should be dynamic, so you can add as much units as you want, and loop over all of them to check for collisions, can you post your whole code, so I can help you, I have made lot of web games

Comment: @SaymoinSam I have put my game on Github, here is the link to the rep: https://github.com/timztreak/The-Collection                               Any help is appriciated.

Comment: So you have only border walls, I mean top, left, right and bottom, to prevent the player from leaving the canvas right?

Comment: Yes, and one wall in the middle that splits the playground

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the players X value with the walls Y value

```
else if(NotP1.x > Wall3.y + Wall3.height && NotP1.x > Wall3.y){
```

That might be a reason why the detection on wall 3 is not working.

I also noticed that you are only detecting the collisions against one axis (X-axis for wall 1 and wall 2. That's fine if they are the play field boundaries. If a player can go around the walls you will need to check for collisions using both the X and Y position.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any suggestion on how I should do it instead ?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed some code inside your collision function

```
function collision(ctx){
  if(NotP1.x <= Wall1.x || NotP1.x >= Wall2.x || 
     NotP1.y <= Wall3.y + Wall3.height &&
     NotP1.y >= Wall3.y || NotP1.y >= 850) {
       NotP1.x = spawn1;
       alert("Player 1 died, Player 2 Wins");
  }

  if(NotP2.x <= Wall1.x || NotP2.x >= Wall2.x || 
     NotP2.y <= Wall3.y + Wall3.height &&
     NotP2.y >= Wall3.y || NotP2.y <= 0) {
       NotP2.x = NotP1.x;
       alert("Player 2 died, Player 1 Wins");
    }
  Wall3.draw(ctx);
}
```

Comment: OH shoot, thank you so much. Havent writen Javascipt alot, any tips on how I could learn more etc ?

Comment: @Timztreak, if you want to learn JavaScript very well download and read this book it's (You don't know JS), it's amazing, I have uploaded it for you https://fv2-3.failiem.lv/down.php?i=p3paw465&download_checksum=b002970af5e10b6cf3136618befd167cc7183413&download_timestamp=1586611304

Comment: Ok, will do. Thank you so much for the help and tips !!